# Error with threads

Tags: c++, pthreads

Hey guys I am having a little trouble with this bit of code.  I dont see anything wrong with it. but it is giving me errors such as

hw2.cpp:35: error: request for member ‘max2’ in ‘my_data’, which is of non-class type ‘thread_data*’
hw2.cpp:35: error: request for member ‘max’ in ‘my_data’, which is of non-class type ‘thread_data*’
hw2.cpp:36: error: request for member ‘max’ in ‘my_data’, which is of non-class type ‘thread_data*’
hw2.cpp:39: error: request for member ‘max2’ in ‘my_data’, which is of non-class type ‘thread_data*’
hw2.cpp:40: error: request for member ‘max2’ in ‘my_data’, which is of non-class type ‘thread_data*’

```
    struct thread_data
        {
          char *file_name;
          int max;
          int max2;
        };

        struct thread_data thread_data_array[NUM_THREAD];

        void *FindNum(void *threadArg)
        {
          int in_num;
          struct thread_data *my_data;
          my_data = (struct thread_data *) threadArg;
  file.open (my_data.file_name);                                                   
  if (file.is_open())                                                                
  cout << "file can not be file"<<endl;  

          while (!file.eof())
            {
              file >> in_num;
              if (in_num > my_data.max){
                my_data.max2 = my_data.max;
                my_data.max = in_num;
              }

              else if (in_num > my_data.max2){
                my_data.max2 = in_num;
              }

            }

          pthread_exit(NULL);
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, `my_data` is a **pointer to a structure**, not a structure. You have to use dereference (`*`) it to get to the structure. Try:

```
my_data->max2 = my_data->max
```

Basically `my_data->max2` is syntactic sugar for `(*my_data).max2`.